# ScrollView is always focusable

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have a problem with `ScrollView` - it is `focusable`. I'm writing a simple app that controled from DPAD. Layout has only ScrollView (empty for now) and a button under it. I don't know why, but `ScrollView` is `focusable` and I can not turn it off. `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` set to `false` not work at all. Activity automatically gives it focus on start. I do not access ScrollView from any part of code, only button. What can it be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a bug in android. `ScrollView` is `focusable` by default and `focusable` can not be set in `layout xml`, but I called `setFocusable(false)` on `ScrollView` after `findViewById` and it works now. Mayby bug in latest support library (I'm using version 25.1.0).

Comment: OMG, still happening as of today with latest all.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug. In the `ScrollView` constructor, there is `initScrollView()`, and in the method, there is `setFocusable(true)`. It is initiated when the app make `ScrollView` instance.